# shortcut for starting and stopping youtube video on second screen on mac

Tags: macbook-pro

I often watch tutorial videos from youtube on my macbook.

So i want to watch the tutorial on my second display and work on my macbook.

Because i often have to start and continue the video i always have to move my cursor back to the other monitor and then tap on the small start button and move back to my macbook display.

i would love to have a shortcut e.g. option-s which starts/stops video or maybe two, one to start, one to stop.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube videos are correctly detected as media in Safari, so the media keys will control playback. F8 (or fn-F8 if function keys are enabled) on Macs without Touch Bar or Play/Pause in the Touch Bar control strip will play/pause the YouTube video.

Comment: thank you, thats great....one reason more to use Safari..... ;) used chrome ...so could not use the touchbar...!